# Reading encrypted multimedia file in memory

Tags: python, encryption

I have a video file which is in some weird looking format that I can't play with vlc. Is it possible to read the binary data from the protected or encrypted file and write it into a .mp4 file?

```
file = open('somefile.mp_14852....')
```

This gives a UnicodeDecodeError. I also tried to specify the encoding to 'utf8' and 'Latin-1' but it still gives the same error.

Comment: `open('filename')` is trying to read a text file, you need `open('filename', 'rb')` to read a binary file. But if you have no idea what format the file is in, and no idea about how to deal with the encryption scheme, it's not going to be easy.  Are you even sure it's encrypted? Find some tool which will tell you where the file came from and what format it is in. But I'm voting to close the question, as there's no possible way to answer how to read a completely unknown file with no information to go on...

Comment: I have a software that's local to the disk the video file is in which can play the file but I want to play it on vlc.

Comment: Just wondering what's the full extension of the file. For example you've put .mp_14852, what's the rest of it?

Comment: its  .mp_1485252983 @JoshuaStokes

Comment: Also what program did you use to originally play the file?

Comment: Its a content browser that's available with the files. You can't find it on the web.